# Rudderstack sdk support for multiple write keys

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, snowflake-stage, rudderstack-sdk

I am using rudderstack to connect two sources to two snowflake destinations for which I am using rudder-sdk-js npm package. In this there is a load method available for loading loading write key and plane url. now I want to load different set of write and plane key-pairs for different functions. my implementation is

```
const rudderanalytics = require('rudder-sdk-js');

export const rudder_initialize = () => {
  rudderanalytics.load(properties?.rudder_key!, properties?.rudder_plane!);
};

export const rudder_feedback_initialize = () => {
  rudderanalytics.load(
    properties?.rudder_feedback_key!,
    properties?.rudder_plane!,
  );
};

export const postRudderEvents = (eventname, data, callback) => {
  rudderanalytics.reset();
  rudderanalytics.load(properties?.rudder_key!, properties?.rudder_plane!);
  rudderanalytics.track(eventname, data, callback);
};

export const postRudderFeedbackEvents = (eventname, data, callback) => {
  rudderanalytics.reset();
  rudderanalytics.load(
    properties?.rudder_feedback_key!,
    properties?.rudder_plane!,
  );
  rudderanalytics.track(eventname, data, callback);
};
```

The functions postRudderEvents and postRudderFeedbackEvents should use different sources, so is there any way to achieve this?

I have tried calling load method for each post event, still it didnt work